# How to save a JSON index position of object, but not the object itself in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, arraylist

Here is my JSON:

```
$scope.myjson = [
                   {id: "1", name: "a"},
                   {id: "2", name: "b"},
                   {id: "3", name: "c", children: [{id: "4", name: "d"}]}
               ];
```

I want to save in javascript the position of object X, for example the position of first object is `$scope.myjson[0]`, but I don't want to save the object itself, I just want the position. On the same way I want to save `$scope.myjson[2].children[0]` .

I must save it a string?
How than I use it to get that object in O(1)?

Comment: What the heck are you talking aboaut?

Comment: Where do you want to save it?  How do you know *which* object needs to be saved?

Comment: I am running over the json with foreach and looking for specific id. I want to save that object position in json, so later on I can really get the object in O(1) without searching my all json again.

Comment: my object position can be: $scope.myjson[1].children[0].children[1].children[4].children[0]

Comment: and where do you want to save that ?

Comment: somehow in my javascript. Should it be a string? Can I than use it to really read that object itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to save the position of the object and not simply the object itself?

If you're looking to cache objects based on an id lookup something like this would work (completely untested):

```
var find = (function() {
    var cache = {}, fn; 

    return fn = function(/*array*/ arr, id) {
       if(cache[id]) return cache[id];
       for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if(arr[i].id === id) 
             return (cache[id] = arr[i]);
          if(arr[i].children && val = fn(arr[i].children, id)) 
             return (cache[id] = val);
       }

       return null;
    }
})();
```

This way subsequent calls to find would return the cached object. Depending on the size of the array and the frequency of lookups, you could also just iterate over it once and create a hash of id => object.